# Sections, subsections numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering, roman

I want to have the following sections numbering style:

> I. Section
>
> A. Subsection
>
> 1. SubSubsection

The following lines of code present different style:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}

\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

> I. Section
>
> I.A. Subsection
>
> I.A.1. SubSubsection

Your help is highly appreciated!

Best regards,

Comment: what about a `\phantom` to include `\thesection` in second command and `\thesubsection` in third? (Not tested)

Comment: In order to get rid of the section number in the subsection title, you could use `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}`. Analogously, you can remove `thesubsection` from the definition of `thesubsubsection`.

Comment: The indented subsubsection number is weird and only useful, if the subsubsection content has an appropriate indent as well

Comment: I find it a bad idea to kill the top - level numbering of subsection etc. As soon as there two or more sections having sub- and subsubsection the numbering repeats and cross-referencing is weird

Comment: I agree it's a strange system, but then again, we've seen other weird requests lately (mostly from thesis commitees...)

Comment: What exactly does @Badrawi want for the spacing before the subsection numbering: a fixed space, or the space taken up by the subsection number? And does he indeed want all three levels to be in the same font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does almost what you want, except for the font sizes:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
    \makeatletter %needed
    % reduce space between number and section title a bit
    \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]%
        {{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{.25em}}}
    % allow more space in ToC for section number (4.5em here)
    \renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.5em}}
    % adjust indentation for the lower levels
    \renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.0em}{1.5em}}
    \renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{3.5em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}    
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}    
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\protect\phantom{\thesubsection}%
    \arabic{subsubsection}.}    

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\protect` in the redefinition of `\thesubsubsection`: the argument of the macro is a moving argument (used in several places, here in the headers and in the ToC), so certain macros (like `\phantom`) need  a `\protect` to avoid compilation errors.

EDIT: Added some extra redefinitions to give space for the longer Roman numerals.

Comment: This was the idea of my comment, but check a `\setcounter{section}{35}` before the first section and see the toc... Doesn't work as expected in toc... So it was a bad idea

Comment: That can be corrected through some other redefinitions, see my edited answer.

Comment: Using your "edited way" I suppose you could just be used  for the fixed space without the `\phantom`. It is now a mix of unrelated ideas. Explaining: The first idea was to use a "dynamic" phantom space that would be adjusted by the compiler... The second is manual fixes and thus doesn't respect the second and will need adjustments anyway. I don't really see a reason to mix these ideas...

Comment: The phantom takes up the space for the section number, the fixed spaces are for the reserved space in the Toc, and space between number and title. A better solution would be to remove the added space in `\thesubsubsection' completely., as Christian Hupfer suggested. A definite answer will have to combine the different bits...

Comment: @koleygr: Your `\phantom` approach would insert the space in a potential reference as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks... I know that... I show it in your discussion... It was just a bad idea as I mentioned... (My idea tested, failed and not became an answer... I could find solutions, but I don't like the document appearance with that change and didn't tried... since it is already solved for the OP... I don't think it will be used again anyway)

Comment: (+1) -- having accepted answers without votes is blasphemy ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Incorporating the space inside of the `\thesubsubsection` is a bad idea since this space will enter the cross-referencing as well, so `\ref{foo}` would give `______1`, where `______` indicates the additional space.

I suggest to change the `\@seccntformat` macro for `subsubsection`, using `\ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp` in order to check whether the counter is `subsubsection` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}.}
\newlength{\subsubsectionnumberindent}
\setlength{\subsubsectionnumberindent}{3ex}

\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{-3.5ex}


\newcommand{\subsubsectionheadingformat}{%
  \hskip\subsubsectionnumberindent\arabic{subsubsection}.\quad%
}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@seccntformat\@seccntformat
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifnum0=\pdfstrcmp{#1}{subsubsection}%
  \subsubsectionheadingformat%
  \else
  \latex@@seccntformat{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


Please see \fbox{\ref{foosubsubsec}}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{SubSubsection} \label{foosubsubsec}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Latex, XeLatex, and LuaLatex didn't like this code (the `\pdfstrcmp`, perhaps?). and it has the same problem @koleygr noticed in my initial proposal

Comment: @remco: Which problem? The spacing in ToC? That's the natural spacing which is there in the ToC anyway. And I did not claim that it would work with LaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX -- those are lacking some features and therefore I don't use them

Comment: A large section number overwrites the title in the ToC.

Comment: @remco: That's the case already even without redefinition of `\the....` stuff. What you achieved by redefinition of `\l@....` can be done with `tocloft` as well, quicker, in my point of view. The O.P. left no information about the real spacing, that's why I did not change the number width